# Got Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0 while learning Spring

Tags: java, spring

I'm learning Spring from the book Spring Start Here. Here, I have added 2 beans of the class Parrot into Spring context, and I'm trying to inject the bean Parrot2 into the Person class using auto wiring through a constructor. However, I keep getting the

"Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type 'beans.Parrot' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: parrot1,parrot2" error. I'm confused how this happened because I didn't think there would be a problem because the Person class constructor parameter matches the parrot2 bean name.

Configuration class:

```
package config;

import beans.Parrot;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;


    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = "beans")
    public class ProjectConfig {

        @Bean
        public Parrot parrot1() {
            Parrot p = new Parrot();
            p.setName("Koko");
            return p;
        }

        @Bean
        public Parrot parrot2() {
            Parrot p = new Parrot();
            p.setName("Miki");
            return p;
        }
}
```

Parrot class:

```
package beans;

public class Parrot {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Parrot : " + name;
    }
```

Person class:

```
package beans;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component

public class Person {
    private String name = "Ella";

    private final Parrot parrot;

    public Person(Parrot parrot2) {
        this.parrot = parrot2;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Parrot getParrot() {
        return parrot;
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
package main;

import beans.Person;
import config.ProjectConfig;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ProjectConfig.class);

        Person p = context.getBean(Person.class);

        System.out.println("Person's name: " + p.getName());
        System.out.println("Person's parrot: " + p.getParrot());
    }
}
```

Error:

```
 Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type 'beans.Parrot' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: parrot1,parrot2
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'person' defined in file [C:\Users\Ian36\IdeaProjects\BENAS\target\classes\beans\Person.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type 'beans.Parrot' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: parrot1,parrot2
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:802)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:241)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1354)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:960)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:93)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:9)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'beans.Parrot' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: parrot1,parrot2
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveNotUnique(DependencyDescriptor.java:218)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:911)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789)
    ... 14 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I tried using @Qualifier to see if it would change anything but I still got the same error.

Comment: What JDK version?

Comment: i’m using jdk 17

Comment: Hm, what version of spring-context are you using?

Comment: i’m using 6.1.2

Comment: It's telling you that it tried to wire in a `Parrot` bean, but found two.  You just need to qualify which one you want to inject into your `Person`.  Add the Qualifier to your `Person` constructor like this  `public Person(@Qualifier("parrot2") Parrot parrot2)`

Comment: @lane.maxwell No need to use `@Qualifier` since jdk9.

Comment: @Grim This has nothing to do with what version of the JDK is being used.  Spring's default autowire is by type.  In this case, the Spring context has two beans of the same type, parrot1 and parrot2, so you must qualify these by name.

Comment: @lane.maxwell Since jdk9 or 8, the constructor-method-argument-names are visible to spring. Thats why no `@Qualifier` is basically  required anymore.

Comment: @Grim Available, but that means nothing to Spring because its default mode of injection is by type.  The OP has already stated he's on JDK17 and the latest version of Spring context, and it's not working because it still needs to be qualified.

Comment: @lane.maxwell Can you tell why my solution works then?

Comment: Just add `-Dmaven.compiler.parameters`.

Comment: @lane.maxwell See, I agree that your solution works ignoring the JDK and maven. My way there is no problem at all because Spring is not reporting multiple-beans-of-type. Following your argumentation every `@Autowired` field must have a `@Qualifier` because the fallback-matcher-by-name hit maybe a second instance of the field-type. Also mention KISS and DRY (dont repeat `@Qualifier(...)`) and "Principle of Least Astonishment" (Need of Qualifier is the astonishment).

Comment: @Grim See my response on your answer

Comment: @Ian What tool are you using to build the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-parameter` is off by default.

Enable it using the pom (since 3.6.2) or use `-Dmaven.compiler.parameters`:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>
<properties>
```

You might update eclipse config using rightclick on the project *Maven*->*Update Project ...*

You will get this output:

```
grim@main:~/workspace/xxx$ mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=main.Main -Dmaven.compiler.parameters

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for aaa:xxx:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 27, column 12
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------< aaa:xxx >-------------------------------
[INFO] Building xxx 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec:3.1.1:java (default-cli) @ xxx ---
Person's name: Ella
Person's parrot: Parrot : Miki
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.293 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-01-02T18:49:53+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
grim@main:~/workspace/xxx$
```

### Reason

Usually the JDK do store the classnames, fieldnames and method-names in the Bytecode NOT store the method/constructor-argument-names. You need guide the compiler to store the method/constructor-argument-names to the bytecode. Only this way spring is able to find the correct candidate for autowiring.

Comment: @lane.maxwell `-parameter` is a JDK thing. No need for maven. Maven is only for easy proof. The op could add `-parameter` in every build-tool, no matter if ant, gradle, cmake. I try always to avoid mvn and use gradle, ant, cmake and mvnd instead because of the environmental health of power consumption. But however maven is spread widely.

Comment: Yes, its a fallback, the hard-coded `@Qualifier` have more precedence and more guarantee to work. If you like to avoid Loose coupling `@Qualifier` is a good bet but then you should avoid CDI in general as pointed out here: https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/part3.html .

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that we just disagree on this.  I'll continue to explicitly use Qualifier if the need arises, mostly because I like to freedom to refactor my code and change those bean-creation method names without having to worry about breaking anything.

Comment: I'm also unsure of how using @Qualifier breaks loose coupling, the Beans are still managed by the IoC container.  If the concern is that you're coupled to Spring, use `@Resource` and `@Inject`.

Comment: @lane.maxwell I agree, both approaches basically work. I meant loose coupling that in runtime you might have no such qualifier but a `@Primary` or a single-instance having a different name what can be injected, or a public-static-final-string holding the bean-name for config and qualifier. Anyway I agree that both ways work and gives no hard feelings. Happy new year btw.

Comment: @grim Happy new year!  Bonus points if you add to this answer the reasons why this works.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You say you tried with @Qualifier, but did you use this notation along with naming the bean? You need to label the bean with a name, then tell the class which needs that bean which one to use, so it would look like this:

```
           @Bean(name="parrot2")
           public Parrot parrot2() {
            Parrot p = new Parrot();
            p.setName("Miki");
            return p;
           }


********

          public class Person {

          public Person(@Qualifier("parrot2") Parrot parrot2) {
             this.parrot = parrot2;
             }
          }
```

If you already tried labeling both sides, then ignore and try something else.

UPDATE: Thanks to @lane.maxwell for corrections.

Comment: Actually, the inverse side of `@Qualifier` is to use the `name` parameter of `@Bean`, so it would read like this, `@Bean(name = "parrot2")`.

Comment: I did a bit more digging. I think @Qualifier works if you use it on a Repository or Service, but not with a Bean declared as such, so I have edited my response. Thank you!